# MoxyContextResolver takes too long to return a JAXBContext

Tags: jaxb, jersey, moxy

Environment: java 7, jersey 2.17 + jersey-media-moxy 2.17

The GET request always expects a FindResponse instance. In my test, I always return the same result. But for every GET request, the MoxyContextResolver is called by the Entity provider (be it json or xml) for the jaxbcontext, and it takes more than 1 minutes for the jaxbcontext to be returned.

In the following code to initialize the application, I have 2000+ JAXB classes.
I can understand if it takes some time to return the jaxbcontext for the first time; but it takes longer and longer as more GET requests are issued.

I tried extend from Application, instead of ResourceConfig and returns my own jaxb ContextResolver as a singleton, but the "*resolvers*" resolves to two jaxb context resolvers, the first one is always the default MoxyContextResolver, the second one is my custom resolver. There's no way for my custom resolver to be used to create the jaxb context.

SamoMoxyApplication.java

```
public class SamoMoxyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public SamoMoxyApplication() {
        super();
        Set<Class> jaxbClasses = new HashSet<Class>(SamoTypeResolver.getSamoJaxbTypes());
        jaxbClasses.add(FindResponse.class);
        jaxbClasses.add(ListWrapper.class);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource("META-INF/config/mdm-oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, url.toString());

        MoxyXmlFeature xmlFeature = new MoxyXmlFeature(properties, classLoader, false,
                jaxbClasses.toArray(new Class[0]));
        register(xmlFeature);

        MdmMoxyContextResolver moxyContextResolver = new MdmMoxyContextResolver(properties, classLoader, jaxbClasses.toArray(new Class[0]));
        register(moxyContextResolver);

        register(SamoMoxyResource.class);
    }

}
```

mdm-oxm.xml (This is all I have in the *xml-bindings* tag, only one LagInterface instance is wrapped in the FindResponse instance in my test)

```
<java-types>
    <java-type name="LagInterface">
        <xml-root-element name="lag.Interface" />
    </java-type>
</java-types>
```